# Suggested Edits rejected by single review

Tags: support, bug

[**This Post**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24258) is reviewed by a single user and rejected by that user alone, On what criteria it happened ?

> [image]

Comment: I think the post was rejected by author of the post. I was checking the post and I found that there was only module title in answer so I update the answer. May be before posting my suggest edit, author has updated his answer and reject my suggestion.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Usually It will show the author name in the summary, suppose if author rejected the edit. but here it is missing.

Comment: I do not have knowledge about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug.

If you look at the [article](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96752/how-to-make-drupal-upload-pasted-links-to-doc-files-from-the-internet/96755#96755), it says clearly that the author is "Beebee".  "Beebee" is also the person who rejected the edit per the screen shot included in the question.

AFAIK, if an author gets to review an edit and rejects it, as single review is all it takes to reject.

Comment: Gisle thanks!!!!!!!!!!!