# Show notification for suggested edit

Tags: discussion, support

I was checking [this](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2792/suggested-edits-rejected-by-single-review) post and I have found that my 16 edit suggestions was rejected by community.

Now, when I checked my suggestion edit list in my profile, then I have to click on "suggested edit" link for each suggestions in the list to check whether its accepted or rejected by community.

I never received any notification on suggested edit. I was assuming that I have lower reputation, so I am not getting any notification.

But, can we show status for each suggested edit in the list of edit suggestion same as we show status for each flag in flag list?

It will help the user like me to know which suggestions was rejected and can improve his edit for future post.

[image: suggested edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [In the page for the suggestions, show which ones have been approved, and which ones have been rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114593/in-the-page-for-the-suggestions-show-which-ones-have-been-approved-and-which-o), where the same feature has been asked two years ago.

It's not a matter of reputation: Nobody would get a notification for each suggested edit that gets rejected or approved. For rejected edits, the reason is that notifications are not used for something that could sound like "you did something bad" as notifications are to incentivate good behaviors; for accepted suggested edits, the reason is that the number of notifications would be too high, for users who make many suggested edits.

The only way to achieve this would be showing in the page listing the suggested edit the result of the review. That is what the old page showed, before it got changed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the the URL. I think, it would be good option if we show status of suggested edit.